# Integrate Spell Checker in TestLink

Tags: testlink

Does anyone know how we can integrate Spell Checker in TestLink tool? There are various spell check extensions specific to browser but those doesn't work in TestLink.

It should work for all text fields in TestLink tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Add the following to cfg/tl_fckeditor_config.js

```
FCKConfig.FirefoxSpellChecker = true ;
FCKConfig.BrowserContextMenuOnCtrl = true ;
```